# Palindrome recursive program in C

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

I've figured out on how to work around the string but I can't seem to get it to work. 
Maybe it's because of the scanf that I'm using. 
Please advise :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int do_palindrome(char *str, int offset){
int ok = 1;
int length = strlen(str);

if(length/2 > 0)
    ok = (str[0] == str[length - 1 - offset])?
            do_palindrome(++str, ++offset):0;

return ok;
}
int main(){
int i = 0;
int ok = 0;
char* str[1] ;

    scanf("%c", str[1]);
    ok = do_palindrome(str[0], 0);
    printf("%s is palindrome? : %d\n", str[0], ok);


printf("Finished!");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: scanf("%c", str[1]); ? only one char ? you need to input string to check for palindrome, isnt it?

Comment: OT: repeating strlen() at every call isn't elegant at all. How about passing remaining length as recursion parameter, instead of the offset ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. The program works if I initialize the code such to :

'char* str[] = {"sasaki", "SOS", "12344321", "1234322",
                                             "555", "0", "ikki"};'

I suppose I should scanf %s to str[0] but that still won't work.

Comment: Nobody will frown if you use indention and code formatting, quite the opposite actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char* str[1] ;
```

declares an array of one char pointer

```
scanf("%c", str[1]);
```

reads a single char but tries to place it beyond the end of your array (C arrays are zero-based).

I think you want to read a string (char array).  You can do this using

```
char str[20]; /* change the array size as required */
scanf("%19s", str); /* read one fewer chars than your array size */
```

Comment: I thought the char *str[1] is supposed to hold a single string?
The program still won't work even if I change it to 20 :(
The code only works if I initialize the string but won't work if I scan for a string.

Comment: You need to allocate memory to hold a string.  You can do this either on the stack - `char str[20]`, or the heap - `char* str = malloc(20)`

Comment: The program works if I initialize the code such to : 'char* str[] = {"sasaki", "SOS", "12344321", "1234322", "555", "0", "ikki"};' I suppose I should scanf %s to str[0] but that still won't work

The working original code is here:
http://pastebin.com/Xuyrh9QH

Comment: @AminHusni Do you want to handle a single string or an array of strings?  Your most recent comment and code like `char* str[]` give arrays of strings but your program looks like it only needs a single string.

Comment: I actually wanted to handle a single string. According to the original 7 string program. I can't seem to grasp the idea of processing a single string instead of 7. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried the code change I suggested in my answer?  Note that you need to use a single char array - `char str[20]`, **NOT** the array of char arrays you have been using - `char* str[20]`

Comment: I see... 
I understand it now but how do I print the whole array?
I will think and alter my function definition. I guess they need to be  modified as well.

Comment: Yes, I got it now! ^^ Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're thinking about is the struct hack:

```
typedef struct {
    char s[1];
} String;

int main()
{
    /* allocate 15 extra bytes for the string */
    String *s = malloc(sizeof *s + 15);
```

This allows you to declare an array of size 1 and then use it as a variable length, but you still have to give it some memory (via malloc) to use it. Then you can access it via `s`.

If you want a variable length string, you should malloc the amount of data you need. If you want to do it a little hacky (and if you're going to compile with Gcc) you can do this:

```
char * str;
scanf("%ms", str);
ok = do_palindrome(str, 0);
printf("%s is palindrome? : %d\n", str, ok);
free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* str[10] ;
scanf("%s", str);
ok = do_palindrome(str, 0);
printf("%s is palindrome? : %d\n", str, ok);
```

You are trying to read a string to char type which is wrong and should be of type string. Also the subroutine call to `do_palindrome` should contain base address of `str` than just first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(length/2 > 0)
    ok = (str[0] == str[length - 1 - offset]) ?
            do_palindrome(++str, ++offset):0;
```

This statement will run `(length - 1)` times. When we check for palindrome, we only need to do `(length / 2)` comparisons. So I suggest to change code to the following:

```
if (length >= 2 && (length / 2) >= offset) {
    ok = (str[0] == str[length - 1 - offset]) ?
            isPalindrome(++str, ++offset) : 0;
```